# Can you fire and overwatch while flying with Archangel armor?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I am at the late game stages and have two colonels who are snipers (both with damn good ground ability and double tap). I have just unlocked the Archangel armor and was thinking that I could outfit both of them with this, so they could fly and fire from top.

Can you fire while flying and go into overwatch while flying as well?

Comment: Yes, you can...

Comment: @SergeyGrinev you should post that as an answer instead of comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A flying sniper *CAN* shoot/overwatch, but *WITHOUT* `Damn Good Ground` bonus.

Check this by press F1 key, before click OK button while shoot.

---

From [XCOM Wiki](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Archangel_Armor_(armor)) *"Flying DOES confer an elevated-position bonus, but you must fly higher than normal."*
So fly higher please.
Sorry for my sloppy experience.

Comment: wow, didn't expect that. But makes sense given you have no `Ground` underfoot while flying :)

Comment: Yes, you are spot on! No DGG bonus :(

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you can.

It's a common strategy to have a sniper with `Squad Sight` flying the whole mission on the edge of the map and kill everything, enjoying safety.